# Excel: select value from multiple id's

Tags: excel

So, I want to find all the id's (there could be multiple) in column orderId.
This is the formula i have...

```
=LOOKUP(INDIRECT("A" & ROW()),Table2[orderId],Table2[quantity])
```

it only selects the value of the last id of said number, how would i write it to select them all and add them together?

Comment: Check this for lookup enquiry: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181212

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for Sumif:

```
=SUMIF(Table2[OrderID],A1,Table2[Quantity])
```

Comment: I'll look this up. First time back in excel since i took it as a req in college